# Reading the PDF file from server in my IPhone application?

Tags: iphone

I have an IPhone application in which i am trying to view the pdf file in the server to my application without downloading it.Can any body help me with meaningfull links or procedures?

Comment: have a look: https://github.com/vfr/Reader https://github.com/schwa/iOS-PDF-Reader

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably misunderstanding, but: 
It can't be done. For anything to be run it needs to go through your cpu, which means downloading it to memory/hard disk/iphone storage. Whenever you "view" a PDF on a computer, it is being downloaded, and discarded when you are finished with it. 


Since I've most likely got the wrong end of the stick, what did you mean by "without downloading"?

Comment: @bugfinder So you want people to be able to view the pdf as it's being loaded?

Comment: i actually want to create an ebook reader part for my application